# Division en postgreSQL muestra resultado incorrecto

Tags: postgresql, sql

Tengo la consulta que me devuelve el valor de un indice que es el resultado de una operacion entre dos columnas, el resultado lo quiero en decimales y lo muestra asi, lo que sucede es que el resultado no el correcto: aca dejo mi consulta:

```
SELECT dep.nombre as departamento,
mun.nombre,can.nombre,cas.nombre,
sum(cap.total_mosquitos) as total_mosquitos,
sum(cap.total_anopheles) AS total_anopheles,
sum(cap.casa_positiva) AS casa_positiva,
sum(cap.casa_inspeccionada) AS casa_inspeccionada,
SUM(CASE casa_inspeccionada WHEN 0 THEN null ELSE 
(total_mosquitos::float/casa_inspeccionada::float) END) AS indice_casa
FROM pl_captura_anopheles cap
INNER JOIN ctl_caserio cas on (cap.id_caserio =cas.id)
INNER JOIN ctl_canton can on (cas.id_canton = can.id)
INNER JOIN ctl_municipio mun on (can.id_municipio = mun.id)
INNER JOIN ctl_departamento dep on (dep.id=mun.id_departamento)
WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cap.fecha)=2018) 
GROUP By dep.nombre,mun.nombre,can.nombre,cas.nombre
```

y el resultado que me muestra:[image: Com vera la primera fila 110/70 muestra 3.16]

EN la primera fila se puede observar el resultado incorrecto 110/70 = 3.16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que me estaba sumando los resultados de division de cada fila, entonces lo que he hecho es sumar primero las columnas y luego ya ese total dividirlo:

```
(sum(total_mosquitos)::numeric/ sum(casa_inspeccionada)::numeric)as indice
```